# How to show that direct sum for a vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $V$ be a vector space, let $P_1$, $P_2$ be linear maps of $V$ into itself. Assume that they satisfy the following conditions.
>   a) $P_1 + P_2 = I $ (Identity mapping)
>   b) $P_1 \cdot P_2 = O$ and $P_2 \cdot P_1 = O$
>   c) $P_1 \cdot P_1 = P_1$ and $P_2 \cdot P_2 = P_2$
>   Show that $V$ is equal to the direct sum of images of $P_1$ ad $P_2$ respectively.

I think I might be misunderstanding the question. Is it to show for each case that $V$ is direct sum of $P_1$ ad $P_2$ or whole set of criteria is required to show it?

So far I've thought

For $a)$ Let $v \in V,(P_1 + P_2)(v) = I(v) = v \in V $ Also $P_1 = I - P_2$ so image of $P_1$ is null space of $P_2$ and vice versa. so $P_1 \oplus P_2$.

For $b)$ Since $P_1 \cdot P_2 = O$ and $P_2 \cdot P_1 = O$, the null space of $P_1$ is image of $P_2$ and vice-versa. By rank nullity theorem it follows.

For $c)$ I don't know, I need help here. Also did I make mistake above?

Comment: You assume that the operators satisfy (a) through (c) simultaneously. In part (c), the condition is actually $P_2 P_2 = 0$? It seems like it should be $P_2 P_2 = P_2$. In any case, what you must show is that every $v\in V$ can be written as $v=P_1v_1+P_2v_2$, and that if $v=P_1w_1+P_2w_2$ as well, then $P_1v_1 = P_1w_1$ and $P_2v_2 = P_2w_2$. Recall the definition of a direct sum: every vector can be written uniquely as a sum of elements from each summand.

Comment: @JohnMyers can we prove that for each case, $V$ is direct sum of $P_1$ and $P_2$

Comment: If c) is really supposed to say $P_2 P_2 = 0$, we would get $$ 0 = P_2 P_2 = P_2(I-P_1) = P_2 - P_2P_1 = P_2$$ and consequently $P_1 = I$, so obviously $V = \operatorname{Im}(P_1) \oplus \operatorname{Im}(P_2)$.

Comment: @AndyBrandi woops sorry ,,, i made terrible typo up there. check again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some notes on your thoughts:

> For $a)$ Let $v \in V,(P_1 + P_2)(v) = I(v) = v \in V $ Also $P_1 = I - P_2$ so image of $P_1$ is null space of $P_2$ and vice versa. so $P_1 \oplus P_2$.

I'm not sure how you get to the conclusion $\operatorname{Im}(P_1) = \ker(P_2)$ but it isn't quite true (see one of my comments).

> For $b)$ Since $P_1 \cdot P_2 = O$ and $P_2 \cdot P_1 = O$, the null space of $P_1$ is image of $P_2$ and vice-versa. By rank nullity theorem it follows.

Unfortunately this doesn't work either. For a counterexample, choose $P_2 = 0$ and any non-invertible linear map $P_1$. Then $\operatorname{Im}(P_1)\subsetneq V$ and $\operatorname{Im}(P_2) = \{0\}$. The reason your argument fails is that $P_1P_2 = 0$ merely implies $\operatorname{Im}(P_2)\subseteq \ker(P_1)$ (and vice-versa), so you cannot apply the rank-nullity-theorem.

For a correct solution, note that for any $v\in V$, $P_1 + P_2 = I$ leads to
$v = P_1 v + P_2 v,$
hence
$$V = \operatorname{Im}(P_1) + \operatorname{Im}(P_2).$$
Now try to show, by using b) and c), that $\operatorname{Im}(P_1) \cap \operatorname{Im}(P_2) = \{0\}$.

Answer (score 1):

You have to assume all the conditions together to get your result. And the last one should be rewritten as $P_2 \cdot P_2 = I$.

Also, please review the definition of direct sum of two subspaces.

Comment: can we prove that for each case, $V$ is direct sum of $P_1$ and $P_2$, could you check what i've written for $a)$ and $b)$
Sorry ,, i made terrible typo up there, i have updated it.

Comment: No. For a), consider the case $V=\mathbb{R}^n$ and $P_1=P_2 = \frac{1}{2} I$.

Comment: To show that b) and c) alone do not suffice, take a 3-dimensional space with basis $v_1, v_2, v_3$, and define $P_i$, for $i=1,2$, by $P_i(v_i) =v_i$, $P_i(v_j) = 0$ for $j \ne i$.